# SQL "select" query

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I'm sure this is super-easy, I just haven't drunk enough coffee today....

So, I have a single table with a few columns, like:

```
NAME1 val1 val2 val2
NAME2 val1 val2 val3
```

There are only about 20 distinct names the first column holds, the values are real but duplicates happen sometimes. I have to find the best ranking row for each distinct NAME.
The ranking is done by sorting first by val1 then val2 then val3

Edit: So here is an example:

```
Ben    2.1 1.0 0.6
Ben    0.1 1.0 0.6
Ben    2.1 0.9 0.1 
Alice  2.1 0.9 0.1 
Alice  2.0 0.9 0.1
```

The answer should be:

```
Ben    2.1 1.0 0.6
Alice  2.1 0.9 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select [name],max(val1) as val1,max(val2) as val2,max(val3)as val3 from sql_select group by [name] order by val1 desc, val2 desc, val3 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by val1, val2, val3
```

You didn't document much, can't be more precise until you give more

Comment: look at 'desc' to reverse the sort